# Searching JSON with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web, web-deployment

I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

```
  $('.searchBar').keydown(function(){
  $.getJSON('js/data.json', function(data){
    var search = $('.searchBar').val();
    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
    $.each(data, function(key,val){
      if((val.id.search(regex) != -1) || (val.title.search(regex) != -1)){
        var img = "<img src= " + val.imgUrl + "/>"
        var title = "<h1>" + val.title + "</h1>";
        var description = "<p>" + val.description + "</p>";
        var cta = "<button><a href= " + val.ctaUrl + ">" + "</a>Find out more about this product</button>";
        $(img).appendTo('#data');
        $(title).appendTo('#data');
        $(description).appendTo('#data');
        $(cta).appendTo('#data');
      }
    });
  });
})
```

UPDATE - this is my JSON file (some of it):

```
"results": [
    {
      "id": "56c1b27e896f0e4141b775b6",
      "title": "Product 1",
      "ctaUrl": "/product-1",
      "imgUrl": "http://placehold.it/275x155",
      "description": "Anim mollit cupidatat duis est adipisicing veniam.Proident culpa voluptate labore consectetur nulla cupidatat eu aliquip ad cillum consequat quis aliquip."
    }
```

Comment: You are most likely getting a `val` that is undefined, so you can't access `val.id` or `val.title` of this element. Log your values using `console.log(val);` and see what you get.

Comment: Either `val.id` or `val.title` or both are undefined.

Comment: I get 5 printed to the console. in my JSON file I do have totalResults": 5. If thats anything to do with it?

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(data)`? I suspect the object is not nested as your code expects it to be

Comment: @DelightedD0D before the if statement I get the JSON back like I thought I would, however after I get nothing out of the console.log

Comment: Is there any other code that you've left out? I dont see anything there that could possibly assign null to `data`

Comment: Please add the 2 console.logs in the code in your question and list the output of each so we can see what you mean

Comment: Could you show us (at least an extract of) your file data.json?

Comment: @cars10 I've done an update

Answer (score 0):

Add a check if `val` contains `id` and/or `title` like this:

```
var textAndId = '';
textAndId += ('id' in val) ? val.id : '';
textAndId += ('title' in val) ? val.title : '';
```

and add to your code this way:

```
$.each(data, function(key,val){
  var textAndId = '';
  textAndId += ('id' in val) ? val.id : '';
  textAndId += ('title' in val) ? val.title : '';
  if(textAndId.search(regex) != -1){
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't targeting the right nude of the JSON file! haha